# How to count number of entries in particular column

Tags: python, csv

I have an excel file with thousands of entries. I want to count the number of entries in the first column.

```
import csv
with open('data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    annotated_data = [r for r in reader]
```

so Now I want to count the entries, I tried doing:

```
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
d = 0
e = 0
for i in annotated_data: 
    if annotated_data[0][i] == A:
        a=a+1
    if annotated_data[0][i] == B:
        b=b+1
    if annotated_data[0][i] == C:
    //continue until E

print("Total number of A:" +a ) //continue until E
```

But it told me "list indices must be integers or slices, not list". so I tried doing

```
for i in range(annotated_data)
```

and it told me "'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

im not sure what else to do, any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating through a list gives you items in the list, not their indices.

So, do this:

```
for row in annotated_data:
    first_cell = row[0]
```

If you really wanted to have the indices, you would have to pass a number to `range`, rather than the list, i.e.:

```
range(len(annotated_data))
```

But I would not recommend doing that. It only makes things slower, less readible, and not compatible with all container types.

If you really needed both indices and items, you could do this:

```
for row_number, row in enumerate(annotated_data):
    first_cell = row[0]
```

Comment: Yeah, I just want to count how many A's, B's... there are, so I dont need the indices. What would I do with the `first_cell` ? Would I check if `first_cell == 'A'` then `a=a+1` ? EDIT: Yeah, I would. Works fine, thanks!

Comment: @AlonzoRobbe Yes, check `first_cell == 'A'`, or check `row[0] == 'A'` directly.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick fix, you may want to try

```
if i[0] == A:
    a += 1
```

etc. Or if you are looking for the literal string 'A', then:

```
if i[0] == 'A':
```

Answer (score -1):

Install pandas using `pip install pandas`
Then, you could do something like this.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('path to file.csv')
print(len(df) + 1)
```

Comment: Although that would work, there is really no need to install pandas (or any other library) in order to do things which work just fine without pandas.

Comment: Absolutely! But using pandas would make the job much more easier. Just my opinion.